# How to get push notification in FCM when child is added in Firebase?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

[Notification is to be sent when a child is added to /ADMIN/Orders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXwMs.png)

[The notification has to be sent to each user who have the same Token ID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6cp9.png)

My node.js code is

```
'use strict'

var topic = "Users";

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.updateOrder =     
functions.database.ref('/ADMIN/Orders/{order_id}').onWrite(event =>{

const order_id = event.params.order_id;

console.log("Today's order is updated!",order_id);

const deviceToken = admin.database().ref(`/USERS/{user_id}/TokenId`).once('value');

    return deviceToken.then(result => {

        const TokenId = result.val();

        const payload = {
            notification: {
            title: "Order is updated!",
            body: "Click to enter Yes/No",
            icon: "default"
        }
    };

    // return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(TokenId,payload).then(response =>{
    return admin.messaging().sendToTopic(topic, payload).then(response =>{

    console.log('This was the notification feature');

});


});
});
```

My cloud function(.js file) is showing successful execution, but still the push notificaiton is not appearing on my phone.

Comment: try To log your Tokens

Comment: How do I do that?